# summernote table add row

Tags: summernote

I've just worked my way through a summernote configuration only to find at the last minute that once you insert a table, it's not possible to change the number of rows or columns. And the editor only supports tables up to 10x10.

For me this makes the table editor in summernote redundant. This issue is reported at https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/93

However, there doesn't seem to be any progress on fixing it. Summernote has a lot of forks - has anybody forked and fixed this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a pull request is there.  Have a look its not my work but a good start.       https://github.com/summernote/summernote/pull/1311

Answer (score 1):

Try following code.

```
  $('#summer-note').summernote({
   // insertTable max size
   insertTableMaxSize: {
     col: 20,
     row: 20
   },
 });
```